# Why are images broken when viewed from sub directories?

Tags: html, image, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Edit: You can see what I mean here: [Test Page](http://thereisnosanity.com/test/)

Images on the page are non relative. They work until moving to /test/n/ or deeper.
The page source shows the images being linked correctly (non relative, correct path) but viewing them, copying their url, and inspecting them with an inline editor show the url as relative and breaks it.

For example, say I use the path http://url.com/images/image.jpg - If I view it from http://www.url.com/n/x/y/
The path remains the same when viewing the source, but elsewhere it's displayed as either /images/image.jpg or http://www.url.com/n/x/y/images.jpg

I find it even more perplexing because linked style sheets and hyper links still work as expected.

I have the following .htaccess file in my test folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#
# Rewrite /test/n/x/y-p/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?n=$1&x=$2&y=$3&p=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
#
# Rewrite /test/n/x/y/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?n=$1&x=$2&y=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
#
# Rewrite /test/n/x-p/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?n=$1&x=$2&p=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
#
# Rewrite /test/n/x/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?n=$1&x=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
#
# Rewrite /test/n-p/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?n=$1&p=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
#
# Rewrite /test/n/
RewriteRule ^([-_a-zA-Z-]*)/?$ index.php?n=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something made you think it is a server side problem. But no, it's not related to Apache, nor .htaccess, nor mod-rewrite.

In fact, the problem is caused by this JavaScript code:

```
function eventSize(){
  if (window.innerWidth < 950)
  {
    document.getElementById('logo').src="template/images/logo_small.png";
  }
  if(window.innerWidth >= 950)
  {
    document.getElementById('logo').src="template/images/logo.png";
  }
}
$(document).ready(eventSize);
$(window).resize(eventSize);
```

It replaces your URL `http://darksociety.org/test/template/images/logo.png` with either `template/images/logo_small.png` or `template/images/logo.png`. But these new URLs don't always work.

To solve it, you can remove that code, fix its URLs, or use regular expressions to gain more flexibility.

For example:

```
var img = document.getElementById('logo');
img.src = window.innerWidth < 950
    ? img.src.replace(/^(.+)(\..+)$/, '$1_small$2')
    : img.src.replace(/^(.+)_small(\..+)$/, '$1$2');
```

The code above will add `_small` just before the extension dot if the width is less than 950 pixels, or remove it otherwise:

```
"http://darksociety.org/test/template/images/logo.png".replace(/^(.+)(\..+)$/, '$1_small$2');
    // "http://darksociety.org/test/template/images/logo_small.png"
"http://darksociety.org/test/template/images/logo_small.png".replace(/^(.+)_small(\..+)$/, '$1$2');
    // "http://darksociety.org/test/template/images/logo.png"
```

This way, even if you change the URL of your image in the HTML, you don't need to update your JavaScript code too.